# Use data from JQuery .get function in an Else If statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I am running a simple .get statement with JQuery:

```
$.get("check.php", function(data)
{
    if (data == "yes")
    {
        $('#thisimg').attr('src' ,'yes.jpg');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#thisimg').attr('src' ,'no.jpg');
    }
});
```

When I call an alert with data as the parameter it returns "yes", however the if statement is still not running and changing the images src.

This is my check.php file:

```
<?php
//connect to db here
//run sql select statement to check whether or not the value is 0 or 1
//value is saved into variable $selected, and the value is 1
if ($selected == 1)
{
      echo "yes";
}
else                    
{
    echo "no";
}
?>
```

Comment: Log `data` in your `console`. `console.log(data);`.

Comment: it outputs "yes" @brso05

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: what is type of the data? try typeof(data) and if your none of statements of your if is called (true block or else block) there must be an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oftentimes there will be an invisible character in returned data. If you [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) `data` it should work:

```
if (data.trim() == "yes")
{
    $('#thisimg').attr('src' ,'yes.jpg');
}
else
{
    $('#thisimg').attr('src' ,'no.jpg');
}
```